# What is preventing tables from being correctly formatted with CSS when table is built by PHP functions?

Tags: php, css, html-table, formatting

I have a table that is built dynamically on my web app. The number of the rows and contents within rows is determined by a series of PHP functions.

Once this is determined, they call another set of PHP functions that create the individual table rows and contain classes to define how they should look. Despite having working tables everywhere else on my app, I can't figure out why I can't get standard  and  formatting to work for this table. The output is ordered into a table but I can't change font size, min-width, background color or anything.

If someone could point out my problem, that would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the PHP function that determines structure:

```
// Determines the core number of buckets and the appropriate general structure for tree
function drawFullTree ($hyp, $b_count, $sb_count, $b, $sb)
{
// loop through *all* buckets
// if any bucket has no-sub buckets, put three (blanks) in it
for($i = 0; $i < $b_count; $i++){
    if(!isset($sb[$i])){
        $sb[$i][0] = '(blank)';
        $sb[$i][1] = '(blank)';
        $sb[$i][2] = '(blank)';
    }
}

echo '<table class="answer">';
    if($b_count > 0){
        if(isset($sb[0])){
            drawBuc_Sub($b[0], $sb[0]);  
        }
        else{
            echo 'sub-bucket blank';
        }
    }
    if($b_count == 0){
        echo 'What! No buckets - lets turn up the effort here!';
    }
    else if($b_count == 1){
        echo "One bucket! Ok, it's a start... keep 'em coming";
    }
    else if($b_count == 2){
        drawTop_Hyp_Buc_Sub($hyp, $b[1], $sb[1]);
    }
    else if($b_count == 3){
        drawHyp_Buc_Sub($hyp, $b[1], $sb[1]);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[2], $sb[2]);  
    }
    else if($b_count == 4){
        drawBuc_Sub($b[1],$sb[1]);
        writeHyp($hyp);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[2],$sb[2]);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[3],$sb[3]);
    }
    else if($b_count == 5){
        drawBuc_Sub($b[1],$sb[1]);
        drawHyp_Buc_Sub($hyp, $b[2],$sb[2]);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[3],$sb[3]);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[4],$sb[4]);
    }
    else if($b_count == 6){
        drawBuc_Sub($b[1],$sb[1]);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[2],$sb[2]);
        writeHyp($hyp);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[3],$sb[3]);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[4],$sb[4]);
        drawBuc_Sub($b[5],$sb[5]);
    }
echo '</table>';
}
```

Here is an example of a PHP function where I can't get formatting applied correctly:

```
function writeHyp_Buc_Sub ($hyp, $buc, $sub)
{
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="x">' . $hyp . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="x">' . $buc . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="x">' . $sub . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

And here is the CSS I have:

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse; 
}


td
{
font-size:.80em;
color: #333333;
padding: 6px 4px;
text-align:left;
/*border-bottom: 1px dotted #cccccc;*/
}

table.answer{
background-color:green;
border:3px black;
}

td.x
{
width:230px;
font-size:1.1em;
border:2px solid black; /*#DCDCDC; */
}
```

the jquery that calls the php functions and inserts it into page:

```
    $('#process_structure').live('click', function () {
    var postData = $('#inputs_structure').serializeArray();
    postData.push({name: 'count', value: count});
    $('#testing').fadeOut('slow');
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "structure_process.php",
        data: $.param(postData),
        success: function(text){
            $('#testing').fadeIn('500', function(){
                $('#testing').html(text);
            })
        }
    });

    $(this).parent().html('<form action="structure.php"><button class="begin_mod_button">Do another!</button></form>');

    clearInterval(interval);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you have the rendered html output produced by that script? Are they producing valid tables?

Comment: Yes. The tables structure and content is correctly rendered (eg, if there are supposed to be 10 rows and X, Y, Z content in certain cells that all displays correctly).

Comment: CSS styling happens once PHP has already finished its job, and html is served to the browser. So, whatever is happening, is not php's fault, as long as it's producing VALID MARKUP. Are you sure there're no overriding settings in your CSS? have you tried styling inline, just as experiment?

Comment: What really counts is the HTML markup.  Can you show that?

Comment: Just because you see the tables you want to see in your browser doesn't mean the markup is valid. Invalid markup will often render correctly or almost correctly because browsers are highly tolerant, but we web devs should never be fooled by it. `View Source` in your browser, inspect the markup to be sure all tags are properly nested and closed. Post that markup here to help us help you...

Comment: I tried styling inline and can't get that to work either. The PHP above is also called through jquery .ajax and inserted into the page - I haven't had problems with this before but I'm posting that code above as well in case it's helpful

Comment: You need to show the finished HTML or a live demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your css in the head of the html document? if not that might be the problem... if you're using IE<=7 (maybe newer versions too) I'm pretty sure this is the solution. IE only renders css on pageload... inline css is not applied on new things inserted in the dom if the css is not in the head section.

since the php are functions I guess they output correct html (you are probably  using them elsewhere). so the only thing that can be wrong (considered the statement above) is your html/css "binding".

Comment: It's only linked from the <head> - are you suggesting the relevant table CSS actually needs to live in the <head> tag of that page? Also, I'm having this problem on Chrome and IE

Comment: I didn't test it but I guess (and may I hope for IE) that linked css in the head must work. I have read in the comments of your question that you tried inline css and it didn't work neither so the problem must be somewhere else. on which browser do you have the error? did you try other browsers? did you validate the html on w3scools, that might reveal some errors too.